# 1)How to get the xpath to get a text without a tag on the same level of other tags

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to get the XPath for "workbasket_598F".However when I giving it //div[contains(text(),'Workbasket Name')]//following::tr[1]/td[1]//div/script it's not detecting the text, it's detecting the

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sGPB.png)

Comment: Please provide at least the url or source-code(as text)

Answer (score 1):

You can get that string with `//div[@class="oflowDivM "]/text()`, which basically will return the text - located inside `<div class="oflowDivM ">` - that is not wrapped in any tags.